# Use overridden static method in JS implicitly

Tags: javascript, function, oop, inheritance, static

Say I've got two classes, `A` and `B`. `B` extends `A`. They look somewhat like this:

```
class A {
    localFunction() {
        return a.staticMethod();
    }

    static staticMethod() {
        return true;
    }
}
class B extends A {
    static staticMethod() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

so I can create a new instance of class `A`

```
const newA = new A();
```

then calling `newA.localFunction()` will return `true` as expected.
but when I create a new instance of class `B`

```
const newB = new B();
```

then call `newB.localFunction()` I still get `true` because the function `localFunction` was never redefined.

I would like the `localFunction` in class `B` to use the static function defined in class `B` however I don't want to redefine it.

Answer (score 0):

> The static keyword defines a static method for a class. Static methods
>   aren't called on instances of the class. Instead, they're called on
>   the class itself. These are often utility functions, such as functions
>   to create or clone objects.

[`static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static#Examples)

```js
class A {
  localFunction() {
    return a.staticMethod();
  }

  static staticMethod() {
    return true;
  }
}
class B extends A {
  static staticMethod() {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(A.staticMethod())
console.log(B.staticMethod())

let newA = new A()
console.log(newA.staticMethod())
```

Comment: yes, I was aware of how it works, I'm simply unsure of a way to make it more dynamic

Comment: @JacobSchneider you want it to be `dynamic` ? than why do you need the method to be `static` ?

Comment: I'm never accessing the `this` context. therefore I do not *need* it to be local. however, as class `B` inherits class `A`, this function should be used from the local class rather than its parent.

Comment: @JacobSchneider but why do you need method to be static ? why not use a normal method ?

Comment: I will be using many instances of class `B`. Therefore maintaining a list of all instances will be memory inefficient, generally inefficient and more or less, more difficult. Plus IntelliJ says to :D

Answer (score 0):

I've actually worked out a clean solution to my issue.

Simply call the static function with `this.constructor` rather than the class name

```
class A {
  localFunction() {
    return this.constructor.staticMethod();
  }

  static staticMethod() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

this.will allow class `B` to override the static method and have it be called in the same way.